# Is it possible to output third-level menu items with wp_get_nav_menu_items?

Tags: wordpress

Stack Overflow Universe,

So possibly a very straightforward question with a straightforward answer, but alas I've been searching for the last 2+ hours for this very query and I can't seem to find the answer.

I'm adapting this mega-menu script (http://selfteach.me/mega-menu-wordpress-without-plugin/ with the full code here: https://gist.github.com/ahaywood/ae3c33ea20f91d8f13e51269a22cb0b1), but try as I might, I can only get 2 levels of a 3 level WordPress menu.

So the straightforward question is:

**Is it even possible to output third level menu items with the `wp_get_nav_menu_items` Function?** Because I've been looking high and low for an answer and every iteration of any `wp_get_nav_menu_items` script only seems to output 2 levels.

Answer (score 0):

```
$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items('menu-slug'); 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($menu_items );
```

you can see there is the list of object, we can use it as our requirement
http://prntscr.com/i7i1y9
http://demo.wordpresshelper.org/46/third-lavel-menu/

Comment: Uhhhh...that wasn't what I was asking. I know you can set up a multi-level menu structure, but I need to output it with wp_get_nav_menu_items in the script format referenced above.